# How do I connect to a listen server I made with another client via batch files?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

```
"C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe" /box:username F:\Steam\Steam.exe +login username password +applaunch 440 +nosound +novid +textmode +sv_lan 0 +mp_idledealmethod 0 +sv_password "serverpassword" +map itemtest
```

I wish to connect to this new tf2 server using a similar batch file 10 minutes after the last steam login without having to make an entire listen server for each account.

For added cookies can someone show me a batch file that will delegate the timing and calling of each of these .bats?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a .bat file, put your first command line there, followed by command `sleep 600`. That will pause processing of the batch file for 600 secs = 10 min.
Followed by next command line, that will be processed when time runs out.
This sadly doesn't work on all Windows versions.
If it woun't work for you, there is a dirtier workaround for pausing a batch file. Use

> ping -n 600 127.0.0.1 > nul

in place of sleep.
Again, this might not work on some other versions of Win ;)

So the whole .bat will look like this:

```
F:\Steam\Steam.exe +login username password
sleep 600
<command to log into server here>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If sleep doesn't work, try TIMEOUT /T 600